# Comments on mobile get squished after editing and canceling

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, mobile-web

Comments get squished against the right side of the screen when editing and canceling on mobile!

Steps to reproduce:

1. **Add a comment.**

   [image]
2. **Tap "edit."**

   [image]
3. **Tap "cancel."**

   [image]
4. **Stare in confusion** and wonder what the unicorns are up to. (or refresh and the comment gets fixed)

After deleting the comment, everything goes back to normal.

I'm using an iPod Touch 4th gen iOS 5.1.1 on mobile Safari. Also reproduced on Galaxy S3 ([thanks Richard Tingle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191315/comments-on-mobile-get-squished-after-editing-and-canceling?noredirect=1#comment594986_191315))

Comment: An interesting thing to investigate might be whether this is related to the iOS rendering engine, or if it's a bug in the mobile version of the site in general.

Comment: I can confirm that this occurs on android standard browser (galaxy s3)

Comment: @Jasper in my career working with it constantly, I've never seen any browser bug in webkit even remotely like the one in the screenshot. Looks like an error in the CSS to me, somebody is using  float incorrectly.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert If you've looked at the code, you've done the research I was talking about. If not, I have no idea how you can come to conclusions as to what this bug is "remotely like".

Comment: Test message...

Comment: No repro on Chrome on iOS 6.1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be available in the next deployment (`rev 2251` on meta and `rev 1609` on the network).